# Rename a symlink with Qt

Tags: linux, windows, qt

I create a symlink using `QFile::link()`function and it works fine but down the road, I want to rename the link. The target remains the same, only the link name changes. Is there a way to do that?

I am interested in both linux (symlinks) and windows (shortcut) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the link, try this

```
QFile linkFile("/path/to/the/file/link_filename"); // remember, windows needs .lnk extension
if (linkFile.exists()) {
   linkFile.rename("/path/to/the/file/new_linkfilename");
}
```

Tested this on Ubuntu 14.04 with Qt 5.5

Comment: I am developing on windows and tried this but doesn't work on windows with Qt 5.4

Comment: I didn't show any error but doens't rename however the first issue was `Qfile::exists()` which in case of symlinks checks for the target file only to return true or false. Than I find it could could be paired with `QFileInfo::isSymlink()` but eventually it turns out I need to delete teh symlink and that is working fine.